# How do MySQLi transactions work?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, transactions

Well, assume we have multiple users.

On every session start `mysqli_connect` is executed. Thus, every user have it's own (?) connection to the DB.

One of users fired an action where the atomic query to the DB should be executed. PHP offers to do something like

```php
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

/* ATOMIC_BEGIN */
mysqli_autocommit($db, false);
mysqli_query($db, "BLAH1");
mysqli_query($db, "BLAH2");
mysqli_commit($db);
mysqli_autocommit($db, true);
/* ATOMIC_END */

mysqli_close($db);
```

Ok, that seems to be pretty simple. However,

> To determine the current state of autocommit use the SQL command ***SELECT @@autocommit***.

The way to determine the `autocommit mode` is the SQL command. It seems that `mysqli_autocommit` is applied not to **the connection for the specific user** but to **the whole DB state**. And thus the transaction can be as below

```php
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

// This one is on the another thread or whatever
// Runned by another user
$db2 = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

/* ATOMIC_BEGIN */
mysqli_autocommit($db, false);
mysqli_query($db, "BLAH1");

// This one is on the another thread or whatever
// Runned by another user
// Not autocommitted since we turned it off
// Can be rolled back
mysqli_query($db2, "QUERY FOR THE ANOTHER USER WHICH BREAKS OUR ATOMICITY AND RESULTS OF THE BLAH2 (E. G. LOGIN)");

mysqli_query($db, "BLAH2");

// Commits both $db and $db2 queries
mysqli_commit($db);

mysqli_autocommit($db, true);
/* ATOMIC_END */

mysqli_close($db);
```

Which is erroneous and completely senseless: other users will login/register only after the `mysqli_commit` action.

I would like to know the correct way to isolate the atomic transactions between users or the mistake I made in my thoughts. My goal is `$db2` query to be executed after the `ATOMIC` section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysqli_autocommit` only affects the current `$link`, it should not interfere with other connections/threads.

The thing that you call `$db` is actually a *MySQLi link resource*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, thought the same way. The method to check the current autocommit state had completely knocked my thoughts...